# C#: Trying to aggregate a dictionary with a tuple<datetime,int> key using the datetime and one of the associated values

Tags: c#, dictionary

I've spent a few hours trying to piece this together but I am having a hard time finding an example. I have a dictionary with a tuple key and a set of values from a class. What I want to be able to do is aggregate (by averaging) the value sets by datetime and a stored value which is my aggregate indicator.

I am really struggling as to how to aggregate based on a single part of a tuple key and a stored value. If it were in SQL it would look something like:

```
select datetime, [aggregate value], avg(myaggregatedfields) 
from dictionary 
group by datetime, [aggregate value]
```

But the tuple is tripping me up on this one. Any help would be appreciated, even if it is pointing toward a tutorial. The reason I used the tuple is that I needed to have those two values to ensure uniqueness.

Comment: can you provide your the code you have so far?

Comment: What framework are you accessing your db with?

Comment: so you loaded your data allready into your dictionary? or is that part of what you want to achieve? and if you filled your dictionary allready, how does the dictionary look like (if the tuple is the value, what is the key)?

Comment: I have added the data to a dictionary, now I am just trying to average those records with the same aggfield.

I am not using a db at this stage, just a class and the dictionary that holds it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe something like this:

```
    class MyClass
    {
        public DateTime Time { get; set; }
        public int OtherVal { get; set; }
        public double AggField { get; set; }
    }




        List<MyClass> lst = new List<MyClass>();

        lst.Add(new MyClass { Time = DateTime.Today, OtherVal = 4, AggField = 1});
        lst.Add(new MyClass { Time = DateTime.Today, OtherVal = 4, AggField = 2 });
        lst.Add(new MyClass { Time = DateTime.Today, OtherVal = 3, AggField = 3 });

        var grouped = lst.GroupBy(c => new Tuple<DateTime, int>(c.Time, c.OtherVal));
        var dic = new Dictionary<Tuple<DateTime, int>, double>();

        foreach (var group in grouped)
        {
            var agg = group.Average(c => c.AggField);
            dic.Add(group.Key, agg);
        }
```